# Transfere bin file to serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a simple GUI that have one task; transfer one bin file to the Serial Port. 
When I test this using two bridged virtual COM ports and a local serial terminal software to receive the data, the software only sends 4096 bytes! The total size of the bin file is 20.000 bytes.

Suggestions?

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = ".txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {

                        sport.RtsEnable = true;
                        while (!sport.CtsHolding == true) ;

                        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                        sport.Write((new BinaryReader(fs)).ReadBytes((int)fs.Length), 0, (int)fs.Length);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: RX buffer Limitation in the serial terminal program receiving the data?

Comment: My Virtual Serial Emulator had a limitation, and I was only allowed to transfere max 4096 bytes.
Replaced with a new type of VSE and everything works perfect.